# How to fix this form fields to be perfect?

Tags: css

I want this form fields just like the red line in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbvDs.png

```css
input,
select,
textarea {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  /* the form is inside this container */
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    <label for="id_image1">profile picture</label>
    <input type="file" name="image1" accept="image/*" required id="id_image1" />
    <label for="id_image2">cover picture</label>
    <input type="file" name="image2" accept="image/*" required id="id_image2" />

    <label for="id_tag">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="tag" maxlength="50" required id="id_tag" />
    <button type="submit" class="button">Upload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I added it, updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with CSS Grid and a little padding.

```css
.wrap,
.field-container {
  display: inline-grid;
}

.field-container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.field-container label {
  padding-right: 2rem;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="field-container">
    <label for="profilePic">Profile picture</label>
    <input type="text" id="profilePic">    
  </div>  
  <div class="field-container">
    <label for="coverPic">Cover picture</label>
    <input type="text" id="coverPic">    
  </div>    
  <div class="field-container">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">    
  </div>      
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/y4fjqaug/11/)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write this, but idk why but it didn't work for me. is there a way to fix my code or should I use like you said grids or maybe flex ..

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code this way, please check if it is suits what you desire:

```
<div class="container">
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
      <div class="rows">
         <div class="column">
            <label for="id_image1">profile picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="image1" accept="image/*" required id="id_image1" />
         </div>
         <div class="column">
            <label for="id_image2">cover picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="image2" accept="image/*" required id="id_image2" />
         </div>
         <div class="column">
            <label for="id_tag">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="tag" maxlength="50" required id="id_tag" />
            <button type="submit" class="button">Upload</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
<style>
   input,
   select,
   textarea {
   width: 55%;
   padding: 12px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin-left: 20px;    
   }
   label {
   width:30%;
   float:left;
   }
   #form{
   width:100%;
   }
   .container {    
   width:40%;
   margin:auto;
   }
   .rows{
   width:100%;
   display:block;
   }
   .column{
   width:100%;
   display:inline-block;      
   }
</style>
```